# D3JS how to get the y postition with bisector?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have big issues to find how to get the y postition with bisector. In the log I have the following error:

```
bisectDate ƒ i(t,n,e,i){for(null==e&&(e=0),null==i&&(i=t.length);e<i;){const o=e+i>>>1;r(t[o],n)<0?e=o+1:i=o}return e}
```

and it is returning me the number of item in the array and not the position id of Y. I dont understand if it's coming from the code or from how the data are stored in the array.

```
var bisectDate = d3.bisector(d => d.date).left,
i = bisectDate(data, x0,1),
```

My array is stored like this :

```
0: {date: Sat Oct 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 20.7}
1: {date: Sun Oct 02 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 21.9}
2: {date: Mon Oct 03 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 22.1}
3: {date: Tue Oct 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 28.8}
4: {date: Wed Oct 05 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 28.7}
5: {date: Thu Oct 06 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 27}
6: {date: Fri Oct 07 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 26.7}
7: {date: Sat Oct 08 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 26.8}
8: {date: Sun Oct 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 56.7}
9: {date: Mon Oct 10 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 60.1}
10: {date: Tue Oct 11 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 61.1}
11: {date: Wed Oct 12 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 61.5}
12: {date: Thu Oct 13 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale), measurement: 64.3}
length: 13
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

here is the complete code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Multi Line Chart</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
<script>
//------------------------1. PREPARATION------------------------//
//-----------------------------SVG------------------------------// 
       const margin = {top: 50, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
       width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
       //width = document.getElementById("container").offsetWidth * 0.95 - margin.left - margin.right,
       height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
       // we are appending SVG first
       // Attention ici il faut que le body possède déjà un DIV dont l'ID est chart
             const svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg") //Creation d'un élément SVG
            .attr("id", "svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            
    //Ajout Titre du graphique
     svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))             
    .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 6))
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")//Text ancré au milieu
    .style("fill", "#6a6a5a")
    .style("font-family", "Raleway")
    .style("font-weight", "10") //Ne change rien...
    .style("font-size", "18px")
    .text("Température sur l'année");

//-----------------------------DATA-----------------------------//
 //Test fonction area dégradé sous courbe  
 const area = d3.area()
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y0(height)
    .y1(d => y(d.close));  
  
//Test Tooltip Mouse over  
  function addTooltip() {
    // Création d'un groupe qui contiendra tout le tooltip plus le cercle de suivi
    var tooltip = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "tooltip")
        .style("display", "none");
    
    // Le cercle extérieur bleu clair
    tooltip.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "#CCE5F6")
        .attr("r", 10);

    // Le cercle intérieur bleu foncé
    tooltip.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "#3498db")
        .attr("stroke", "#fff")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
        .attr("r", 4);
    
    // Le tooltip en lui-même avec sa pointe vers le bas
    // Il faut le dimensionner en fonction du contenu
    tooltip.append("polyline")
        .attr("points","0,0 0,40 55,40 60,45 65,40 120,40 120,0 0,0")
        .style("fill", "#fafafa")
        .style("stroke","#3498db")
        .style("opacity","0.9")
        .style("stroke-width","1")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-60, -55)");
    
    // Cet élément contiendra tout notre texte
    var text = tooltip.append("text")
        .style("font-size", "13px")
        .style("font-family", "Segoe UI")
        .style("color", "#333333")
        .style("fill", "#333333")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-50, -40)");
    
    // Element pour la date avec positionnement spécifique
    text.append("tspan")
        .attr("dx", "-5")
        .attr("id", "tooltip-date");
    
    // Positionnement spécifique pour le petit rond bleu
    text.append("tspan")
        .style("fill", "#3498db")
        .attr("dx", "-60")
        .attr("dy", "15")
        .text("●");
    
    // Le texte "Cours : "
    text.append("tspan")
        .attr("dx", "5")
        .text("Temp. : ");
    
    // Le texte pour la valeur de l'or à la date sélectionnée
    text.append("tspan")
        .attr("id", "tooltip-close")
        .style("font-weight", "bold");
    
    return tooltip;
}   
    const timeConv = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");
    const dataset = d3.csv("data2.csv");
         dataset.then(function(data) {
          var slices = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
          return {
            id: id,
             values: data.map(function(d){
                return {
                    
                    date: timeConv(d.date),
                    measurement: +d[id]
                };
            })
        };
    });
//Affichage pour console dbugg des données reçues Activation sur navigateur touche F12  
console.log("Column headers", data.columns);
console.log("Column headers without date", data.columns.slice(1));
// returns the sliced dataset
console.log("Slices",slices);  
// returns the first slice
console.log("First slice",slices[0]);
// returns the array in the first slice
console.log("A array",slices[0].values);   
// returns the date of the first row in the first slice
console.log("Date element",slices[0].values[0].date);  
// returns the array's length
console.log("Array length",(slices[0].values).length);
//----------------------------SCALES----------------------------//
   const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0,width]); //Position départ et longueur axe x
   const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]); //Position départ et longueur axe x
   xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
    return timeConv(d.date)}));
    yScale.domain([(-15), d3.max(slices, function(c) { //Chiffre début et fin de l'échelle Y
        return d3.max(c.values, function(d) {
        return d.measurement + 10; }); //Retourne la valeur max et ajoute 10 en y
        
        })
    ]);

//-----------------------------AXES-----------------------------//
     const yaxis = d3.axisLeft() //Définition des données de l'axe y
    .ticks((slices[0].values).length)
    .scale(yScale); //Appel de yScale

     const xaxis = d3.axisBottom()//Définition des données de l'axe x
    .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d'))
    .scale(xScale);
            
//----------------------------LINES-----------------------------//
     const line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })//Attribue de l'echelle en y
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.measurement); }); //Attribue de l'echelle en y
    //Attribue une id à chaque courbes
     let id = 0;
     const ids = function () {
     return "line-"+id++;
                             }  
//-------------------------2. DRAWING---------------------------//
     //svg.append("linearGradient")
    //.attr("id", "areachart-gradient")
    //.attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
    //.attr("x1", 0)
    //.attr("x2", 0)
    //.attr("y1", y(d3.min(data, d => d.close)))
    //.attr("y2", y(d3.max(data, d => d.close)))
    //.selectAll("stop")
        //.data([
            //{offset: "0%", color: "#F7FBFE"},
            //{offset: "100%", color: "#3498DB"}
       // ])
    //.enter().append("stop")
        //.attr("offset", d => d.offset)
        //.attr("stop-color", d => d.color);
     //var areaPath = svg.append("path")
    //.datum(data)
    //.style("fill", "url(#areachart-gradient)")
    //.style("opacity", "0.6")
    //.attr("d", area);



//-----------------------------AXES-----------------------------//
     svg.append("g") //Dessine l'Axe x
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xaxis);
     
     svg.append("g") //Dessine l'Axe y 
    .attr("class", "axis") //Mise en forme CSS
    //.attr("y1", y(d3.min(data, d => d.close)))
    //.attr("y2", y(d3.max(data, d => d.close)))
    //.attr("y1",-10) //Limite basse
    //.attr("y2",35) //Limite haute
    .call(yaxis) //Appel propriétés yaxis
    //.call(ybaxis)
    .append("text") //Ajout de l'indice T°c sur axe y
    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("x", 20)
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("T°c");

//----------------------------LINES-----------------------------//
     const lines = svg.selectAll("lines")
    .data(slices)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

    lines.append("path")
    .attr("class", ids) //Attribue une classe à chaque courbes pour CSS (mise en forme)
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
                        //Ajout nom des courbes
                         lines.append("text") 
                        .attr("class","serie_label")
                        .datum(function(d) {
                         return {
                         id: d.id,
                         value: d.values[d.values.length - 2]}; })//Position selon x
                         .attr("transform", function(d) {
                         return "translate(" + (xScale(d.value.date) + 0)  
                         + "," + (yScale(d.value.measurement) + 5 ) + ")"; })
                         //.attr("x", -5)
                         .text(function(d) { return (" ") + d.id; });
                         
    
    var tooltip = addTooltip();
    
    //var bisectDate = d3.bisector(d => xScale(d.date)).left; //Ici on devrait récuperer la valeur date position souris
    //var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return xScale(d.date); }).left;
    //var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]);
    //var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return x0; }).left;
    //console.log("bisectDate",bisectDate);
    
    
    svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function(event) { 
        tooltip.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(event) {
        tooltip.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);
    
    function mousemove(event) {
    var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0])
    var y0 = yScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0])
    var bisectDate = d3.bisector(d => d.date).left,
    //bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left,//Le problème est ici !!!!!!
    
    //const mousePosition = d3.mouse(this);
    //var x0 = xScale.invert(mousePosition[0]),//Donne la valeur sur l'axe X date position souris
    //var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event)[0]),
    //var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event[0])),//d3.pointer(event[, target]) 
    //var y0 = yScale.invert(mousePosition[1]);//Donne la valeur sur l'axe y position souris
    
        i = bisectDate(data, x0,1),
        //i = bisectDate(data, d.date),//Ne fonctionne pas !
        d = data[i-1]; //Fonctionne recupère un array fonction de i
    //console.log("Table date",d.date);
    console.log("bisectDate",bisectDate);
    console.log("Seeking Date",slices[0].values[2].date); 
    console.log("x0",x0);
    console.log("i",i);
    console.log("d",d);
    //tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xScale(d.id) + "," + yScale(d.id) + ")");
    
    d3.select('#tooltip-date')
        .text(d.date)
        .attr("y", 12);
    d3.select('#tooltip-close')
        .text(d.TInt + "C");
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i finally find a solution with adding this :

```
var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y%m%d")
w=formatDate(x0);
i = bisector(data, w, 1);//WORKS
```

So i hope i will help someone.

I run a lot of time around this